# Arguments delimited by blank space in a macro

Tags: programming

I work on postscript objects and I need to transform lines like

```
109.8516 58.404 moveto 
102.7108 70.7583 88.4258 67.3824 82.4704 64.0235 curveto
```

or

```
109.8516 58.404 m
102.7108 70.7583 88.4258 67.3824 82.4704 64.0235 c
```

in the PGF/TikZ format. I have 20,000 lines and I also need to use as few number of characters as possible. A good solution is to avoid the braces and to keep the blank spaces. Actually, I use the following code:

```
\def\p#1#2{\pgfqpoint{#1bp}{#2bp}}% 
\def\m #1 #2 {\pgfpathmoveto{\p{#1}{#2}}}%
\def\l #1 #2 {\pgfpathlineto{\p{#1}{#2}}}% 
\def\c #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6 {\pgfpathcurveto{\p{#1}{#2}}{\p{#3}{#4}}{\p{#5}{#6}}}%
```

with

```
\m 109.8516 58.404  
\c 102.7108 70.7583 88.4258 67.3824 82.4704 64.0235
```

The problem: I need to use a blank space at the end of each line and I would like to avoid this blank space. Moreover, I'm not sure if my code is correct.

Complement: My idea is to create a version of the  [psvectorian](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/) package for PGF/TikZ. I am translating the file `psvectorian.pro` to a file `pgflibraryvectorian.code.tex`. All the vector ornaments are created with the pgf basic layer. Perhaps it's not a good idea and I might try to compress this file. My project is here : [pgfvectorian](http://altermundus.com/SandBox/project_vectorian.zip)

Comment: Do you get these lines with `\input` or `\read`?

Comment: I use a script to transform `109.8516 58.404 m` and to get \m 109.8516 58.404. The first line come from a .eps file.

Comment: Why not adding also a final delimiter? Change `109.8516 58.404 m` into `\m 109.8516 58.404\end` and do `\def\m#1 #2\end{\pgfpathmoveto{\p{#1}{#2}}}`

Comment: no because I get 20,000 \end in my file and I don't want this. I would like nothing after the last digit.

Comment: It can be anything that's not a digit: `Z`, for instance; so the size wouldn't be affected.

Comment: yes but nothing will be preferable if it's possible ! Z is better that a blank space because it's more easy to control but if my script is correct, logically the last blank space is unhappily here.

Comment: It's always a problem delimiting the arguments of a macro with the end-of-line, but not so difficult to solve. Would you please add some information to your question about what you're actually doing?

Comment: Another idea would be to remove the last blank space and all the "end of line" and to get a file with one line but I don't know if it's a realistic  idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2264/discussion-between-altermundus-and-egreg)

Comment: @Altermundus You can delimit by itself `\def\m #1 #2\m{...}` use as `\m109.8516 58.404\m` anything can really do as the last delimiter. Not sure if I can understand your answer to egreg's comment.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides about the 20,000 \end ? I actually use a blank space for delimiter, I can use Z or something like this because after the last digit the next character is "EOF" or `\`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would reformat the contents of `pgflibraryvectorian.code.tex` as follows:

```
\makeatletter

\def\pgf@@vectorian@p#1#2{\pgfqpoint{#1bp}{#2bp}}%
\def\pgf@@vectorian@m #1 #2Z{\pgfpathmoveto{\p{#1}{#2}}}%
\def\pgf@@vectorian@l #1 #2Z{\pgfpathlineto{\p{#1}{#2}}}% 
\def\pgf@@vectorian@c #1 #2 #3 #4 #5 #6Z{%
  \pgfpathcurveto{\p{#1}{#2}}{\p{#3}{#4}}{\p{#5}{#6}}}%

\def\pgf@@vectorian#1{%
  \begingroup
  \let\p\pgf@@vectorian@p
  \let\m\pgf@@vectorian@m
  \let\l\pgf@@vectorian@l
  \let\c\pgf@@vectorian@c
  \@nameuse{pgf@@vectorian@#1}%
  \endgroup}

\@namedef{pgf@@vectorian@1}{%
%def\@pgfvectorianX{136}\def\@pgfvectorianY{107}%   vec1
\m 109.8516 58.404Z
\c 102.7108 70.7583 88.4258 67.3824 82.4704 64.0235Z
\c 76.5236 60.6518 72.9472 60.6518 69.3794 75.2496Z
\c 65.7988 89.856 49.1309 90.9713 38.418 90.9713Z
\c 27.7056 90.9713 32.4678 106.6973 32.4678 106.6973Z
\c 9.8485 79.7409 25.3228 66.2628 38.418 62.8953Z
\c 51.5219 59.5279 49.2228 58.0494 34.8502 49.4172Z
\c 21.7545 41.5499 27.7056 31.4434 24.1335 19.0934Z 
...
\c 87.4827 79.2025 91.3928 77.6427 105.0731 80.4119Z 
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}}

\@namedef{pgf@@vectorian@2}{%
%def\@pgfvectorianX{133}\def\@pgfvectorianY{48}%     vec2
\m 132.9548 23.3771Z
\c 131.3683 31.9185 119.1886 48.1506 83.3983 47.7588Z
...
\pgfpathclose
\pgfusepath{fill,stroke}}

...

\makeatother
\endinput
```

This avoids both having a gigantic `\ifcase` in one macro and the problem of terminating the `\l`, `\m` and `\c` macro arguments with an invisible final space.

Comment: Little mistake `\@nameuse{pgf@@vectorian@#1}%` you forgot the second `@`. I take your code but I replace `\let\m...` by `\def\m ##1 ##2 {\pgfpathmoveto{\p{##1}{##2}}}%` and I remove the first `\def`. Something very strange : I keep on using `##1 ##2 `with a blank space after 2 and I remove all the blank spaces at the end of lines. The code seems to compile correctly. Why ? EOF is like a blanck space ?

Comment: @Altermundus Yes, at the end of a line there's always `^^M` that TeX converts into a space *provided* another `^^M` doesn't follow. This is why delimiting the final argument with a space is risky.